# How to find the union of two lists in tcl?

Tags: list, tcl

I'm familiar with finding the intersection of two lists, however, I wanted to find the union of two lists in tcl (while eliminating duplicates). I do have a working copy of this code, but I'm not sure it is robust enough for any kind/number of lists and am hence looking for a better solution.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you treat lists as sets, so you don't worry about order if the items, you could just sort the joined list:

```
set union [lsort -unique [list {*}$list1 {*}$list2]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Tclx provides a union command:

```
% info patchlevel
8.5.9
% set a [list a b c]
a b c
% set b [list a d e]
a d e
% package require Tclx
8.4
% union $a $b
a b c d e
% 
% union
wrong # args: should be "union lista listb"
%
```

Comment: Tclx implements `union` almost exactly like Sergei's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info @glennjackman. Appreciate it! To an end user, I think it makes sense to use a native/bundled API/command than trying to re-write it .

Answer (score 3):

One way that doesn't need sorting is to use dictionary keys as sets:

```
% set a [list a b c]
a b c
% set b [list a d e]
a d e
% set d {}
% foreach k $a { dict set d $k . }
% foreach k $b { dict set d $k . }
% set c [dict keys $d]
a b c d e
```

This has the advantage of not needing to sort at all, which can help quite a lot with large input sets.

Comment: Is there a way to cram the elements of a list into a dict as keys without iterating over the list?